# Can anyone help me avoid being detected when using mock locations on an app, I have decompiled and pasted a code from it,s smali file

Tags: android, apk, decompiling, smali, mock-location

```
.line 1854
invoke-virtual {p1}, Landroid/location/Location;->isFromMockProvider()Z

move-result p1

goto :goto_6

.line 1856
:cond_d
iget-object p1, p0, Lcom/bel/HYS/FileexplorerActivity$NetworkHitLatLong;->this$0:Lcom/bel/HYS/FileexplorerActivity;

invoke-static {p1}, Lcom/bel/HYS/FileexplorerActivity;->access$100(Lcom/bel/HYS/FileexplorerActivity;)Landroid/content/Context;

move-result-object p1

invoke-virtual {p1}, Landroid/content/Context;->getContentResolver()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;

move-result-object p1

const-string v7, "mock_location"

invoke-static {p1, v7}, Landroid/provider/Settings$Secure;->getString(Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object p1

const-string v7, "0"

invoke-virtual {p1, v7}, Ljava/lang/String;->equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

move-result p1

xor-int/2addr p1, v5

:goto_6
if-eqz p1, :cond_e
```

I tried fixing the value of p1 by `const/4 p1, 0x0` after the line containing `isfrommockprovider()Z` but the problem persisted. I also tried to change `if-eqz p1` directly to goto but it still didn't resolve.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To help you with your question, we need some more details. In particular: What do you want to achieve? What is the app that you're decompiling? Why are you decompiling the app? And what have you tried so far? Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly modifying `p1` after the `invoke-virtual` call

```
invoke-virtual {p1}, Landroid/location/Location;->isFromMockProvider()Z
move-result p1
...
```

is not a good idea. Because the return value of `isFromMockProvider()` will be written one command later by `move-result p1` into `p1`. So changing it before that will not have any effect as it is overwritten by `move-result`.

As invoking `isFromMockProvider()` has no other effect than the return value I would replace both calls shown above (`invoke-virtual` and `move-result`) by the line

```
const/4 p1, 0x0
```

If it still doesn't work then this is not the only check.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I searched other files and found 2 other files having similar checks, now it works,